# unable to install pypi package on GCP Composer

Tags: airflow, pypi, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to install pypi package, sentence-transformers, it failed.
I am getting error message suggested me to find error in build-log-webserver. but no error log in build-log-webserver.
Can anyone suggest some advice on this issue.

Error message:

> Failed to install PyPI packages. Check the Cloud Build log at the
> build-log-webserver log for details.

On   build-log-webserver log  I checked:

```
 {
textPayload: "Successfully installed dataclasses-0.7 filelock-3.0.12 joblib-0.17.0 nltk-3.5 packaging-20.4 regex-2020.10.15 sacremoses-0.0.43 scikit-learn-0.23.2 scipy-1.5.3 sentence-transformers-0.3.8 sentencepiece-0.1.91 threadpoolctl-2.1.0 tokenizers-0.9.2 torch-1.6.0 tqdm-4.50.2 transformers-3.4.0"
....
resource: {2}
timestamp: "2020-10-21T07:28:14.154802526Z"
receiveTimestamp: "2020-10-21T07:28:17.412076290Z"
}
```

Comment: Error message:
Failed to install PyPI packages. Check the Cloud Build log at the build-log-webserver log for details. 

On   build-log-webserver log  I checked:
 {
textPayload: "Successfully installed dataclasses-0.7 filelock-3.0.12 joblib-0.17.0 nltk-3.5 packaging-20.4 regex-2020.10.15 sacremoses-0.0.43 scikit-learn-0.23.2 scipy-1.5.3 sentence-transformers-0.3.8 sentencepiece-0.1.91 threadpoolctl-2.1.0 tokenizers-0.9.2 torch-1.6.0 tqdm-4.50.2 transformers-3.4.0"
....
resource: {2}
timestamp: "2020-10-21T07:28:14.154802526Z"
receiveTimestamp: "2020-10-21T07:28:17.412076290Z"
}

Comment: Could you please mention your Composer image version and all the desired PyPi packages you have specified?